# Please help me out sending the email through WindowsXP Telnet

Tags: email, telnet

I want to send an email to any email address using Windows XP telnet. I opened the command prompt and typed telnet after enabling telnet. It successfully connects me to the SMTP servers of Gmail, Yahoo and Live. But whenever i start giving commands for sending email, it gives me some errors.

1 - After writing telnet on command prompt, the command prompt shows this..

```
Welcome to Microsoft Telnet Client

Escape Character is 'CTRL+]'

Microsoft Telnet>
```

2 - Then i type open smtp.gmail.com 587

```
Welcome to Microsoft Telnet Client

Escape Character is 'CTRL+]'

Microsoft Telnet> smtp.gmail.com 587
```

3 - Pressing enter shows me this message..

```
220 mx.google.com ESMTP e6sm9347529wiz.1
```

4 - Then i type HELO and it replies this message...

```
220 mx.google.com ESMTP e6sm9347529wiz.1
HELO
250 mx.google.com at your service
```

5 - When i type, MAIL FROM: myname@gmail.com, it gives error message.

```
220 mx.google.com ESMTP e6sm9347529wiz.1
HELO
250 mx.google.com at your service 
MAIL FROM: myname@gmail.com
502 5.5.1 Unrecognized command. e6sm9347529wiz.1
```

6 - When i give it my email address instead of above address, it gives this error message

```
220 mx.google.com ESMTP e6sm9347529wiz.1
HELO
250 mx.google.com at your service 
MAIL FROM: myname@gmail.com
502 5.5.1 Unrecognized command. e6sm9347529wiz.1
MAIL FROM: shy.girl96@yahoo.com
530 5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS command first. e6sm9347529wiz.1
```

7 - Typing StartSTL Port 587, it gives this message

```
555 5.5.2 Syntax error. e6sm9347529wiz.1
```

I am stucked here. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. The protocol required to send mail over GMail's port 587 (SUBMISSION) requires SSL negotiation, which is impossible to do by hand.

Comment: @duskwuff... can you tell me some other email service that can easily work with telnet. I just want to know practically how it works.

Comment: Sending email using Telnet is no longer possible with most ISPs.